# Ensuring data integrity of Firestore exports

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, export

I followed the following guide to set up automated imports and exports for my firestore database:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

However, the docs specify that

> An export may include changes made while the operation was running.

Are batched transactions safe, or should I disable write access while a export is taking place?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "unsafe" about the exports.  You just have to realize that you don't get a guarantee about the contents of the export, given that the export doesn't represent a snapshot in time of the entire database.  The database could be changing over time while the export happens, and the contents of all of the documents don't necessarily come from the point in time when you initiated the export.  It's not possible to change this behavior.  Your best bet is to simply lock down access to the database while the export is happening so you can guarantee for yourself some sort of consistency.

As such, exports are not suitable for what many people would consider a "backup".  It's merely a convenience for you to save and load the contents of a database without having to write code.